# Issue with row selection UITableView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a view controller with following layout:

- Container View

  - `UIScrollView`

    - `UITableView` as a sub view of a `UIScrollView`

I have another `UITableViewController` in which I have a few rows and some methods when the row gets selected. Now I want to display this `UITableview` inside the `UIScrollView`. So I add the `UITableView` as a subview of `UIScrollView`. The table is displayed in the scroll view just fine, but when I tap in the scroll view to select the table's row, then row is being highlighted but the method is not getting called when the row is selected..

```
    PBDashboardPickupTable *dashtable = [[PBDashboardPickupTable alloc]initWithNibName:@"PBDashboardPickupTable" bundle:nil];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:dashtable.tableView];
```

Also I have set scroll view's `delayContentTouches` to `YES` and `cancelContentTouch` to `NO` from Interface Builder. Also `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `YES`... then why is the method not getting called when I tap the table view's row?

Answer (score 0):

Apple specifically warns in the documentation to avoid putting a `UITableView` inside of a `UIScrollView`:

> **Important**: You should not embed `UIWebView` or `UITableView` objects in `UIScrollView` objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Since `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, I would suggest you add any additional views you need as a `tableHeaderView`, `tableFooterView`, or as custom cells in the table.