# uitable view scroll to bottom issue after dismissing modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a problem with my table view scrolling to bottom. I tried to search stack overflow for a solution but nothing could help.

Here is what I have:
I have a table view that I'm loading extra cells into each time the user scrolls to the bottom of it. I did it as follows:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1))
        //load more data..
}
```

after the data gets loaded successfully through an internet connection, I'm calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` to refresh the table and increase its size.

Now here comes the problem:
When the user selects a cell, a details view controller is presented. I noticed that before presenting the details view, the table is quickly resized to its original size showing only the initial number of cells inside.

When the details view is dismissed, the table view comes back to its original size (without fitting the data loaded on `willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:`) and there is no way it could be scrolled down till the end of all data.

I checked all these points, but nothing helps:

- the data in table view is reloaded by calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `viewWillAppear` method.
- the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the table view are set correctly to the container view controller.
- checked calling `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` when the view appears again, and it is returning the exact number of all the data I have, but the problem is in the table not fitting its size to my total data.

I also tried to resize the table frame as follows:

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.size.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
self.tableView.frame = frame;
```

But nothing changes.

Any help please??

Update:
I'm doing nothing unusual in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. The code is simply:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailsViewController *vc=[[DetailsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Post code for `didSelectRowForCellAtIndexPath:` if you are doing something unusual.

Answer (score 0):

1. take object of uiscrollview in uiview
2. take object of uitableview in uiscrollview
3. set the property scrollenabled = flase of uitableview
4. write the delegate method of uiscrollview

   ```
   - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
   {
           if (scrollView == scrollObj)  {
                   CGFloat scrollPosition = scrollObj.contentSize.height - scrollObj.frame.size.height - scrollObj.contentOffset.y;
                   if (scrollPosition < 30) {
                           if ((!spinnerBottom.isAnimating) || intGetDataCallRunning == 0) {
                                   //[spinnerBottom startAnimating];
                                   //[self getLoginFollowingUserVideosCall];
                                   //run WebService call and after that reload the table or if you have data exists then only reload the table
                                   //and after reloading table follow step no 5.
                           }
                   }
           }
   }
   ```
5. after reload the table set height of table and scroll

   ```
   tblVideo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, tblVideo.contentSize.height);
   scrollObj.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,tblVideo.contentSize.height+60);
   ```

Comment: You mean I should place the table inside a scroll view ??

Comment: yes, add table inside the scroll. and step 3 is very important for this

Comment: I tried your fix above, but unfortunately, I got no data displayed on the table at all!

Besides, It is not recommended that you place a table view inside a scroll view as stated in this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127525/issue-with-row-selection-uitableview-inside-uiscrollview

I finally got my problem fixed by doing the following these steps:
1- Setting the tableView.contentSize to a previously saved value on viewWillAppear.
2- Setting the scroll position to a  previously saved value on viewWillAppear.
3- Calling [tableView setNeedsDisplay]
4- Calling [tableView reloadData]